# How strong are the checksums in Ethereum addresses?

Tags: addresses, icap, checksum

2 options for Ethereum addresses which have checksums are ICAP and [EIP55](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/55).  Are there others?

For each option, how strong are the checksums?  What is the chance that a typing mistake (or mistakes) will still lead to a valid Ethereum address?

Comment: EIP issue #55 is no EIP at all (yet?).

Comment: Oh, didn't realize so many EIP55 comments added in the past week.

Answer (score 2):

## EIP55

For each address, there is a `1 / 146,150,163` chance that it will not contain any alpha characters and thus cannot be checksummed.  On average, an address will have `15` alpha characters which results in **15 bits** of checksum data. This means that on average an address that passes the checksum has roughly a `1 / 32,768` or `1 / 2^15` chance of being a false positive.